# Scaling Docker Containers with isolated networks

Tags: shell, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I'm using docker-compose (v 3.3) and I have a set of services as shown below.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  jboss:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: jboss/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - ${NETWORK}
    #  - front-tier
    #  - back-tier

  mysql:
    hostname: mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 3306
    networks:
      - ${NETWORK}
    #  - back-tier

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:1.7.3
    ports:
      - 9200
    networks:
      - ${NETWORK}
    #  - back-tier

networks:

#  front-tier:
#   driver: bridge
```

The problem/question is related to the possibility to isolate these services when I scale my containers in a kind of subnet (by the way, I'm not using swarm here) in the sense that jboss1 can only see mysql1 and elasticsearch1. The same for jboss2 - mysql2 - es2 and so on. I know this is quite strange, but the task is to parallelize some tests and they must be completely isolated.

[image: Isolated containers]

As you probably have realized, I've tried some approaches (that are commented in the compose) of defining some networks, but if I scale the containers, they will obviously be on the same network - which means that I could randomly ping on mysql-n from jboss-1.

Then, I tried another approach explained here by Arun Gupta http://blog.arungupta.me/docker-bridge-overlay-network-compose-variable-substitution/ where he mentioned the variable substitution in the network attribute (for that the ${NETWORK} there). But it turns out that if I try to "up" my containers via:

```
NETWORK=isolated-net1 docker-compose up -d
```

and then

```
NETWORK=isolated-net2 docker-compose up -d
```

it won't scale the containers, but instead, recreate them all:

```
Recreating docker_mysql_1 ...
Recreating docker_elasticsearch_1 ...
Recreating docker_jboss_1 ...
```

In a nutshell: Is there a way to isolate a group of services when doing a `docker-compose up --scale`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it turns out that after a few days where I've been beating my brains out and trying to find a proper out-of-the-box solution for the problem, the feasible way to achieve this (actually, the one which fits my needs) was doing the following:

I. Creating the specific volume for the instance that would call the other containers (in this case, JBoss):

```
jboss:
    build:
      context: jboss
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    # ... omitting the rest
```

II. Slightly editing my Dockerfile with a script that really does the isolation:

```
FROM my-private-jboss:latest
ADD isolateNetwork.sh /opt/jboss/jboss-eap/jboss-as/server/default/bin/isolateNetwork.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/jboss/jboss-eap/jboss-as/server/default/bin/isolateNetwork.sh
CMD ["/opt/jboss/jboss-eap/jboss-as/server/default/bin/isolateNetwork.sh"]
```

III. Finally, the isolateNetwork.sh (warning: I had to install jq on my JBoss container to help in these extractions from docker API):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

curl -s --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/containers/$(hostname)/json > container.json
export DOCKER_CONTAINER_NUMBER=$(cat container.json | jq -r '.Config.Labels["com.docker.compose.container-number"]')
export DOCKER_PROJECT_NAME=$(cat container.json | jq -r '.Config.Labels["com.docker.compose.project"]')

export MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME=${DOCKER_PROJECT_NAME}_mysql_${DOCKER_CONTAINER_NUMBER}
export MYSQL_IP=$(curl -s --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/containers/$MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME/json | jq -r '.NetworkSettings.Networks[].IPAddress')

#Now it's just required to edit the Datasources
find . -iname "MySql*-ds.xml" -exec sed -i s/mysql:3306/${MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME}:3306/g {} +
```

As you can see, the volume created during step 1 serves to access docker API from inside a container. This way, I could query the info mentioned and edit the configuration to invoke just upon the same `DOCKER_CONTAINER_NUMBER`. Apart from that, it is important to mention that my command to scale has a very specific requirement that is: every Jboss will have the same number of data-sources, which implies that `DOCKER_CONTAINER_NUMBER` will ever match.

```
docker-compose up --scale jboss=%1 --scale elasticsearch=%1 --scale mysql=%1 --no-recreate -d
```